# I received an error message while trying to install datatable in python 3.7.4 using python -m pip install datatable

Tags: python, installation, py-datatable

When I tried to install a datatable using `pythom -m pip install datatable` in python 3.7.4, I received the following error message:
 Complete output (26 lines):

```
Start setup.py
  command = `install`

Find an LLVM installation
  Environment variable LLVM is not set
  Environment variable LLVM7 is not set
  Environment variable LLVM6 is not set
  Environment variable LLVM5 is not set
  Environment variable LLVM4 is not set
  Candidate directory `/usr/local/opt/llvm` not found
  The build will proceed without Llvm support

Determine the compiler
  Environment variable `CXX` is not set
  Environment variable `CC` is not set
  Llvm installation not found, cannot search for the clang++ compiler
  'compiler_cxx'
  Compiler `clang++.exe` is not found
  Compiler `gcc.exe` is not found

Prepare the environment


SystemExit: Suitable C++ compiler cannot be determined. Please specify a compiler executable in the `CXX` environment variable.

----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Kazerooni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\KAZERO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v4t9g3f2\\datatable\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\KAZERO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v4t9g3f2\\datatable\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\KAZERO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tjfm4gd6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Datatable will support Windows starting from version 0.11. As of right now, it is possible to install dev snapshots of datatable, see the instructions at https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install datatable on Windows. That is not yet supported.

https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/1114